# Training a bidirectional LSTM is unstable

Tags: deep-learning, lstm, keras

I'm trying to solve timeseries classification problem. That's my model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(32, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True), input_shape=(1000, 1), merge_mode='concat'))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(4, activation='softmax')))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='RMSprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I've got strange plots of my training. Training is unstable either for training or validation. Is it wrong?[image]